# Convert (csv) string object to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

My character object looks like this:

```
"ID,MONTH_ID,FLAG\n70,201001,1\n71,201001,1\n94,201001,1\n95,201001,1\n102,201001,
1\n110,201001,1\n124,201001,1"
```

I want to convert it to data frame with every `\n` a new row should be created.

Can someone please help me in this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try :

```
x <- "ID,MONTH_ID,FLAG\n70,201001,1\n71,201001,1\n94,201001,1\n95,201001,1\n102,201001,1\n110,201001,1\n124,201001,1"
df <- read.table(text = x, sep =",", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

which gives:

```
   ID MONTH_ID FLAG
1  70   201001    1
2  71   201001    1
3  94   201001    1
4  95   201001    1
5 102   201001    1
6 110   201001    1
7 124   201001    1
```

Comment: @Sonal glad to know. you may check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- "ID,MONTH_ID,FLAG\n70,201001,1\n71,201001,1\n94,201001,1\n95,201001,1\n102,201001,1\n110,201001,1\n124,201001,1"
l <- strsplit(x, "\n")
df <- as.data.frame(l)
```